# Setting up another FAQ for money.SE

Tags: discussion

This question is prompted by a discussion following [a question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/16645/5760) on money.SE.  The standard FAQ of money.SE is similar (if not identical) to the FAQs on other stackexchange sites, but what would really help is another FAQ with answers to the questions that do indeed truly get asked frequently on money.SE and which could well be closed promptly and the OPs directed to the repository of stock answers to common questions.

Over on math.SE, there is a [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/15941) that is maintained on the meta.math.SE site. Perhaps the moderators can consider setting up something similar on money.SE or meta.money.SE too? I will nominate @littleadv's [recent answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/16649/5760) as something that can go on 
meta.money.SE's *List of Answers to Commonly Asked Questions.*

Comment: This is a good question but you should ask it at the **meta** site.  I'm migrating it.

Comment: Hmmm I thought I asked the question on meta.money.SE. At least, I clicked on the "Ask Question" link on meta.money.SE and began writing...  Oh, well, it got to the right place.

Comment: I don't think I've ever written on math@SE:)

Comment: I just looked at that page on math and my head exploded.

Comment: @littleadv and MrChrister too.  Please, folks, I didn't mean that littleadv's answer should go on math.SE's list but on a newly set-up money.SE's list. I have edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: Oh, I meant to say you got the link to my "recent answer" wrong:)

Comment: @littleadv OOOps.  Thanks for pointing that out. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Should we use the tags as the topics?  I suggest we fill out the tag wikis and then create a link to the most popular tags in our existing FAQ.